# How can you protect yourself from mythic magic missiles?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic, mythic-adventures

I am in a mythic game as a cleric. Our martial character is worried about [mythic magic missile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Magic-Missile) and at first I dismissed his concerns until I started examining it for myself.

As everyone can imagine, [magic missile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile) can get out of hand when its [metamagic master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master), [empowered](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic---final), [maximized](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/maximize-spell-metamagic---final), [quickened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic---final), and heightened (before using the mythic versions of those same feats).

So lets just gloss over that and get directly to mythic magic missile (MMM). The augmented version basically removes any protection from MM that existed, and what it didnt the [heightened spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/heighten-spell-metamagic---final) still took care of. So that's [shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield), [spell immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spell-immunity), [globe of invulnerability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/globe-of-invulnerability),  [ring of forcefangs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-forcefangs), and so on.

So the only remaining methods that I can think of are

- Concealment and either force the missiles to have a miss change or have nothing to target
- forms of an antimagic field
- Counter Spell/dispel magic

So what realistic choices do people have in countering this pretty powerful mythic spell?

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 6):

Have enough hit points that a magic missile spell doesn't kill them? Which if you're up against someone who can "mythically quicken, empower, etc." a spell should always be the case.

I suspect many of these problems you're asking about are from just reading the rules and not from actually playing the game.  In high level and mythic play, the single biggest factor is the action economy.  Using an action on magic missile means you're not using that action (and spell slot) on something even worse, like every other non-first level spell.  If I can do a super duper empowered mythic *magic missile* spell, or a, say, mythic persistent heightened *flesh to stone*, the latter is usually a better one-round killer.

I played in a Wrath of the Righteous mythic campaign and our caster had mythic *magic missile* - and used it when running low on other stuff, or when a little extra surefire damage would take out a wounded foe - in other words, whenever you'd use a normal magic missile in non-mythic mid-level play.

There's some mythic powers and stuff that can protect even against mythic spells - but that's not the real answer to this question. "Because there's something better to do with that action" is the real answer.

Comment: MMM has line of sight as range which is a huge advantage. You can see the enemy general at the other side of the battlefield? Boom. The arch wizard steps out of his tower? Boom. The princess is walking in the garden? Boom. A martial PC should be able to survive on HP alone, but for many characters a well planned MMM can kill.

Answer (score 3):

## Talk to the GM about the [*brooch of shielding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/brooch-of-shielding)

The missiles created by the [mythic *magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Magic-Missile) spell "bypass the [*shield*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield) spell and similar effects that block the non-mythic version of this spell," but the [*brooch of shielding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/brooch-of-shielding), despite the name and despite using the spell *shield* in its construction, does not, technically, *block* the missiles from a *magic missile* effect: "[I]t can absorb *magic missiles* of the sort generated by the spell or spell-like ability[, absorbing] up to 101 points of damage from *magic missiles* before [the *brooch*] melts and becomes useless."<sup>1</sup>

The *brooch of shielding* (1,500 gp; 0 lbs.) is, however, extremely narrow in function, can't be recharged, *and* occupies the wearer's neck slot, which is extremely valuable personal real estate. By using the rules for [Adding New Abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Adding-New-Abilities) to magic items, with the GM's permission, a *brooch of shielding* effect could perhaps be added to another inexpensive and slotless item (e.g. an [*ioun stone* (dull gray)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/dull-gray-stone-ioun-stone) (25 gp; 0 lbs.)) for 2,250 gp. (Both *brooch* and *stone* are [wondrous items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wondrous-item-item-creation---final) and, as there's no trend of magic items that absorb spells occupying the neck slot, adding the *brooch*'s effect to the *stone* shouldn't be an issue; see Altering Existing Magic Items under [Magic Item Slots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Items-Slots) for *Pathfinder*'s heartless limits to such effects.)

But, because using the *brooch* to defend against mythic *magic missiles* is reliant on a technicality, the GM could rule (and, perhaps, equally technically, maybe correctly, seeing as how the *shield* spell *is* used in the *brooch*'s creation, after all) that the *brooch* is no defense against the mythic *magic missile*, ruling that the terms *block* and *absorb* are here close enough to be synonyms. This GM, though, given the lengths the creature's gone to to make itself—briefly!—immune to something as rare and weird (in this GM's campaigns, anyway) as *magic missile* effects, *would* let such a defense function, even against a *mythic magic missile* spell. The *brooch* will be slag soon enough under an assault by any competent [mythic *magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Magic-Missile) [Metamagic Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master) mage.<sup>2</sup>

### About that [mythic *magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Magic-Missile)…

An [empowered](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic---final) (+2) [maximized](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/maximize-spell-metamagic---final) (+3) [quickened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic---final) (+4) 1st-level [*magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile) spell cast by a creature possessing the trait [Metamagic Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master) (*magic missile*) (−1) spends one of that creature's 9th-level spell slots. While a level 20 caster's version of such a *magic missile* spell can be cast as a swift action, it deals only 25+((5d4+5)/2) points of damage, or, on average, about 43 points of damage. That's not only embarrassing but also pitiful for a 9th-level spell slot. A similarly beefed up [mythic *magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Magic-Missile) deals a more impressive 90+((20d4+10)/2) points of damage, or, on average, about 120 points of damage—more impressive but *still* a 9th-level spell slot *and* costing of 2 uses of mythic power. Although, the line-of-sight range and ability to bypass spell resistance and even spell immunity *are* excellent benefits of mythic *magic missile*. I can imagine the efficacy of such a spell being taught in wizarding classes: reliably picking off foes on the horizon is pretty cool, and for a caster with the correct trait, the spell's only 5th-level if it needn't be quickened (the mythic power cost will limit its usefulness, though).

So while your party's warrior can worry about this spell, the party's unlikely to encounter the spell a lot unless the GM routinely punishes players by dealing their PCs (45+((10d4+10)/2)) points of damage seemingly out of nowhere by sticking [flying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly), [*greater invisibility*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility)-using mythic tier 4+ wizard 9s on every horizon.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> I must add here that I really enjoy authors making *absolutely certain* the reader knows what a particular rhetorical flourish *actually* means in game terms, like *melts **and** becomes useless* so that there's no argument about a melted *brooch* continuing to suck up *magic missiles*. My favorite example of this is from *AD&D*'s *Monster Manual* (1978): "If a [mind flayer's] tentacle hits it will reach the opponent's brain in 1-4 melee rounds and draw it forth, immediately killing the creature" (70), y'know, just in case a player at the table argues, "Hey, I'm a fighter! What do I need a brain for!?"
<sup>**2**</sup> Probably far fewer creatures *should* have the trait [Metamagic Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master) than do. The regional trait originally appeared in the [*Dragon Empires Primer*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8pg0?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Dragon-Empires-Primer) as Wayang Spellhunter (14), and, as the name and provenance suggests, a GM may limit the trait's availability to those from a region like Golarion's [Minata](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Minata) which is populated largely (but not exclusively) by [wayangs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-wayang).

Comment: Not the trait magical linage which does only reduce the metamagic requirement by one, but the feat which gets applied for each metamagic feat applied to the spell.

Comment: The shield spell negates magic missile, so since the broach negates force effects, it is also bypassed as a similar effect.

Comment: Well, nowhere says it can't be countered either. So that's another defense.

Comment: @Fering The trait Metamagic Master says, "When you use the chosen spell with a metamagic feat, it [the spell] uses up a spell slot one level lower than it normally would." Hence, no matter how many metamagic feats are applied to the picked spell, the total reduction is just by 1, but you can ask that as another question if you want.

Comment: The brooch doesnt block force effects or or the spell, it absorbs de damage. The spell functions fully against the character, but part of the damage is absorbed by the brooch.

Comment: @Fering I'm not sure how much more carefully I can couch the answer. The *brooch* absorbs but doesn't block the *magic missiles* effect, but it's technical enough that even the title is *Talk to the GM*. Did you already?

Comment: And, of course, suggestions for improvement are welcome.